# Please recommend a physics problems book similar to Demidovich

Tags: soft-question, education, resource-recommendations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graduate Physics Problems Books](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10325/graduate-physics-problems-books)

Does anyone have recommendation for a physics problems collection book (series) that is similar to Demidovich's [*A Collection of Problems and Exercises in Mathematical Analysis*](http://books.google.com/books?id=jYn2HAAACAAJ)?  I am looking for the encyclopediac coverage and Russian editorial style, if you like.

## Update:

I'd like problems for 1) senior undergraduates major in physics and/or 2) Ph.D. candidates in physics

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2451

Comment: Have a look at the Schaum series, they have a lot of solved problems. For example [here](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Advanced-Calculus-Third/dp/0071623663). There are too some Schaum titles for basic physics ([here](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-College-Physics-11th/dp/0071754873)) and some topics, like Lagrangian Mechanics, [see here](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Lagrangian-Dynamics-Wells/dp/0070692580/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358411798&sr=1-1&keywords=schaum+lagrangian).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know at what level you want the problems. Some excellent sources for olympiad level problems are :

1. [Irodov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8183552153)
2. [Krotov](http://www.flipkart.com/aptitude-test-problems-physics/p/itmdytgby9abebha?pid=9788123904887)
3. [200 puzzling physics problems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521774802)

The last one is especially good. For undergrad level physics problems, it is best you refer to individual textbooks.

Comment: If you solve Irodov, you'll probably be able to solve anything else in the 'general physics' sense ;) So I agree with ramanujan_diracs choice :)