# Quantum mechanics problem solving book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Can you suggest me some problem solving books for quantum mechanics ;that will help me develop more physical intuition along with mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36019/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Aha! But i must begin from somewhere. Any recommendation?