# Exercise books for Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams

I know QFT at graduate level but I'll like to master the skill of working with Feynman diagrams. I'm looking for a book of solved exercises on this topic.

Specifically, I'm looking for the kind of repetitive exercises, just like in elementary school you have to do e.g. 10 multiplications, 10 divisions, etc. I haven't found anything like that.

The topics I'm interested in are, for example, calculating invariant amplitudes, cross sections, etc. from Feynman diagrams, computing the Feynman rules from some Lagrangian theory and calculating the lower order tree expansion, etc.

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean when you say you know QFT but still need practice with Feynman diagrams. I would suggest just trying to work out the examples in textbooks like Scrednicki and Peskin, if you haven't already. Also you can peruse the web for classes people have taught where HW exercises and solutions have been posted. Better yet, just get involved with some research and you will learn what you need to know.

Comment: @DJBunk it means that I have taken one course in QFT and preparing for an exam for the second course (from graduate school). So I've done exercises (some of them from the basic books you cite, others from lecturer's own notes) and one exam. But I feel like I need more practice for this other exam and the problems I've done are not enough for me to feel like I've really mastered it. I was thinking of making my own exercises and using CompHEP to check my answers but that takes some time as I have to code the theories in the program which I only know the basics

Comment: [This](http://www.amazon.com/1000-Solved-Problems-Modern-Physics/dp/3642043321) sound like the kind of thing you're looking for? I've seen some similar ones in my uni library - don't remember the details at the moment, but such books do exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2451

Comment: Found [the book](http://www.amazon.com/Gauge-Theory-Elementary-Particle-Physics/dp/019850621X) I was talking about. As I recall it's a good one for field theory.

Comment: @MichaelBrown, the first one is too elementary, and the second seems nice but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Qmechanic, those are too elementary and not related at all.

Comment: Hi @Barefeg. Phys.SE only allows a few book recommendation and big-list questions, cf. extended discussion on our meta site. One reason is that else we would e.g. drown in such lists instead of getting any actual physics done. It is much better to ask an actual conceptional question about what you do not understand about, say, in this case, Feynman diagrams. That way you have solved at least one problem instead of having yet-another-list-of-things-to-read-in-the-future.

Comment: @Qmechanic, in this case I do understand Feynman diagrams, I just wanted to practice by repeatedly applying the concepts and techniques I already know. That way my hand is "warmed up" for an exam. But if this kind of questions is not allowed in the site then you can delete it or close it or whatever you think is best for the site. The thing is confusing is that there exist a tag for books...

Comment: @Qmechanic just to say, the question linked to as duplicate does not yet have an answer pointing out a resource for Feynman diagram exercises. Maybe the hints given in the comments here could be posted, by Michael Brown for example, as a new answer there. Provided that nobody closes the earlier duplicate question too of course ...

Comment: People who diagree with this recent change in policies, which disallows questions about any study material and references (papers) or education, instigated by David Zaslavsky and a few other powerful people without the whole community having a saying about it, you should have a look at [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4202/2751) meta thread and vote accordingly. There are some people who disagree with these new policies, but they are not powerful enough. Study material/reference questions should exactly be allowed for the site to be useful for students and researchers in physics.