# Goldstein's Classical Mechanics exercises solutions

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Does anyone know where I can find some (good) solution of Goldstein's book *Classical Mechanics*?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2451

Answer (score 0):

Try Googling, he is your friend:

- [First entry](http://www.slideshare.net/venuatsrr/solution-manual-classical-mechanics-goldstein)
- [Second](http://homerreid.ath.cx/physics/goldstein/)

And so on

Comment: I asked for GOOD solutions. So I'm interested in opinion about various solutions and not to randomly search it on Google.