# A set of problems for "The Theoretical Minimum" Stanford course

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm really excited by an opportunity to watch Leonard Susskind's course "The Theoretical Minimum". However, I couldn't find any physics problems on [the website](http://theoreticalminimum.com/), and I'm a little bit wary of just watching videos. I want to think on some problems during that.

Maybe there's a good collection of Physics problems on related themes, so I could try them between the videos?

Comment: 't Hooft has a reference [website](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html) The  links often have some problems

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2451