# Introductory exercise set with solutions for string theory

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I am trying to self-study string theory, beginning with Ibanez and Uranga (String Theory and Particle Physics). Unfortunately, the book contains no problems, so I'm not sure whether I am fully understanding the material.

Are there any pedagogical string theory problem sets, for a beginner, preferably with solutions, available on the web that would accompany my book? I.e. questions initially covering the quantization and symmetries of the Nambu-Goto and Polyakov actions, the wordsheet etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/2451

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4408

Comment: @user26143 thanks, unfortunately that solutions manual doesn't contain the questions themselves, and I don't have the Polchinski book.

Comment: Zwiebach's book *A First Course in String Theory* has a lot of problems.