# Problem books like I.E. Irodov for advanced physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I really enjoyed doing problems from Irodov while learning introductory physics. But I am not able to find a book like that for Graduate level physics. Can you suggest me a book which has good (and hard) problems from advanced topics like Quantum Theory, QFT, Relativity, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graduate Physics Problems Books](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10325/)

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was quite good but I only had it on loan, so didn't do that many problems 
Problem Book in Quantum Field Theory by Voja Radovanovic http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problem-Book-Quantum-Field-Theory/dp/3540770135